# Regex: find defined string between html tags

Tags: java, regex, groovy

From Jenkins I'm using Confluence API for getting the content of a page in HTML such like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Bla1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <div class="content-wrapper"><p><time datetime="2022-07-25" />&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">what I’m searching</td>
        <td colspan="1">2</td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <div class="content-wrapper"><p><time datetime="2022-07-25" />&nbsp;</p></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">Bla3</td>
        <td colspan="1">3</td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <div class="content-wrapper"><p><time datetime="2022-07-25" />&nbsp;</p></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

What I want is to Update the content of a particular line of a table where I just know the value of a string, in this case “what I’m searching”, so what I need is a regex that match everything inside a table row and the searched string:

```
<tr> ... what I’m searching</td> ... </td> .(after 90 till 100 char). </td></tr>
```

matching also two times the `</td>`,once the closing after a lenght of 90 till 100 chars `</td></tr>` and returns the entire row as follow:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="1">what I’m searching</td>
    <td colspan="1">2</td><td colspan="1">
        <div class="content-wrapper"><p><time datetime="2022-07-25" />&nbsp;</p></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rather simple look-up like yours, you don't really have to use any external tools, a simple regex would perfectly do.

Also, it's going to be more performant and less resource-hungry.

I'd put it like so:

```
String txt = '''\
<tr>
  <td>bla1a</td>
  <td>bla2a</td>
  <td>bla3a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>bla1b</td>
  <td>what I’m searching</td>
  <td>bla3b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>bla1c</td>
  <td>bla2c</td>
  <td>bla3c</td>
</tr>'''

List res = ( txt =~ /(?s)<tr>(\s*<td>[\w\s]+<\/td>\s*)*<td>what I’m searching<\/td>(\s*<td>[\w\s]+<\/td>\s*)*<\/tr>/ ).findAll()*.first()

assert res == ['''<tr>
  <td>bla1b</td>
  <td>what I’m searching</td>
  <td>bla3b</td>
</tr>''']
```

Comment: Hi @injecteer, thank you so much, this is almost what I need, I have forgotten to mention that I have a slightly more complex string to regex. I’ve edited the question, can you provide a regex for this case?